# Word font size information using Tesseract

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to perform certain post processing operations on the ocr output from Tesseract in Python using Pytesseract module, which requires word font size information. I know that font size information can be retrieved using Tesseract  because [Tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs) provides such information(eg. Word font size, all individual character choices with respective confidence values) in the ocr output but i don't know how to get the same with tesseract binding in Python.
Is there any other python binding for tesseract lib to get such information?

Comment: If it helps - the *WordFontAttributes* function which provides the font size is located [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/src/ccmain/ltrresultiterator.h), but I don't know of any python wrappers which support that too.

Comment: Thanks @DmitriiZ. for the response, i am aware of this function but i am not able to invoke this function from Python.

Comment: Seems like it is supported with [this](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) wrapper

Comment: Yes, it provides the choice iterator https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr#iterator-over-the-classifier-choices-for-a-single-symbol